# Custom Panning Methods for Google Maps V3

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to have a custom control on my Google Map v3 so I can take control of the focus for dpad navigation on GoogleTV.  I am looking for a way to pan with each click of the directional arrows...just like the built in panControl.  Is there public methods to pan right, left, down, and up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [reference on google.maps.Map methods](http://code.google.com/intl/cs/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map), in particular method `panBy()`:

> panBy(x:number, y:number) ...... Changes the center of the map by the
>   given distance in pixels. If the distance is less than both the width
>   and height of the map, the transition will be smoothly animated. Note
>   that the map coordinate system increases from west to east (for x
>   values) and north to south (for y values).

Comment: Thank you again Tomas T.! How do I know the width and/or height of the map?  Is there a map.getWidth type method?  I know there's not a getWidth...just looking for something of the like.  I tried this for panning to the right to no avail map.panBy(map.getWidth()/8, 0);

Comment: @taraloca, there is a `map.getDiv()` method and then it reduces to the problem how to get the div dimensions. If you use some javascript framework e.g. jquery you can do `$(map.getDiv()).width()` to get the width. Otherwise you would have to use some DOM features and it will not be so easy.